# Cordova android issue

Tags: android, cordova

Hi there I am newie in cordova

I have successfully installed the latest version of cordova through CLI and after creating a project and i am seeing a new folder as **platform_www** folder and no cordova.js file inside the **libs folder** can any one tell me how to proceed with the situation,while importing the project into eclipse it is showing error as Cordova activty not recognized.

Comment: Please try following the guide in the documentation and asking any questions you get stuck when following that guide. This way we will be able to improve the docs. The guide is at: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: I have done same procedure still it is showing the same way "MBillau"thanks for the quick response ,but can you try once installing the latest version and check out yourself the situation

Comment: Got it nothing is wrong in the process after creating two to three times . Now it is not showing any error,i have created project ,with the latest version of cordova 3.3 we will get an additional folder as pltforms_www and after importing into eclipse the cordova.js adds as a library file